# Coveralls notifies when there are no changes

Tags: travis-ci, coveralls

Here are my repo settings:

[image]

So I expect notifications only if something changes. But it continues to inform me of the following letters:

*"Coverage remained the same at 100.0% when pulling [commit-hash] **on dev** into [commit-hash] **on master**."*

How to fix it?

---

**Edit:** I think this happens only with PRs. But anyway...

Yeah, I also use Travis CI, where Coveralls check triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! I got it, it is not Coveralls' notifications, it is GitHub notifications, which you can manage on 'Settings' page. These messages were sent because Coveralls left comments on PRs in repository I am watching.